# Trying to use iosTouch js for hover

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, hover

I have hover effects I am using that work great for desktop but need them to work on mobile devices as well. I tried to follow a Youtube video on adding iosTouch with mootools to allow a hover like effect for ios devices. I am doing something wrong in my code and can't get it to work. I added the mootools    to my head. Here is the rest of my code.

```
<div class="page" id="resume">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h2>Resume</h2>
      <div class="row">

        <blockquote class="col-sm-6" id="qualifications">
          <div class="quote">
            <span class="intro" id="iosTouch">Qualifications</span>
            <span class="more">
              <ul>
                <li>Excellent communication skills, both oral and written</li>
                <li>Ability to quickly learn and apply new technologies</li>
                <li>8 years of experience developing curriculum for instructor-led, web-based and blended modalities</li>
                <li>2 years of experience creating HTML web pages including the testing and debugging of code</li>
              </ul>
            </span>
          </div>
        </blockquote>
    </div><!--row-->
</div><!--content container-->
</div><!-- resume page -->
```

The JS I added is:

```
//fix hover events for ios
$("iosTouch").addEvents({
    touchstart: function() {
        $("iosTouch").addClass('more');
    },
    touchend: function() {
        $("iosTouch").removeClass('more');
    }
});
```

My CSS is:

```
#resume {
padding: 0; 
border-top: 40px solid transparent; 
}

#resume blockquote {
margin: 0;
padding: 0; 
border-left: none;
min-height: 500px;
position: relative;
}

#resume blockquote .quote {
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
padding: 20px 5%;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 75%;
font-weight: 400;
border-radius: 0 50px 0 0;
}

#resume blockquote .quote:hover {
background-color: rgba(255,199,96,.9);  
}

#resume #qualifications {
background:url(../images/resume_qualifications.jpg) no-repeat center center;
background-size: cover; 
}

#resume .quote .more {
opacity: 0;
font-size: 0;
line-height: 0;
padding-top: 10px;  
}

#resume .quote:hover .more {
font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
font-weight: 100;
display: block;
opacity: 1;
font-size: .8em;
line-height: 120%;  
}

#resume .quote .intro::after {
content: '...'; 
}

#resume .quote:hover .intro::after {
content: '';    
}
```

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You're simply using the `jQuery` (`$`) function wrong. Replace `$("iosTouch")` with `$("#iosTouch")`.

This is because jQuery attempts to emulate css selectors for getting DOM objects, and in CSS, `#` targets divs.

Without the `#` it implies that you want to perform the function on a tag called iosTouch.

Comment: Found something that works. In case anyone else is hunting down a similar solution here is a link to where I found what worked for my code: http://codepen.io/mickeykay/pen/wiLno